# Delete all the queues from RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I installed `rabbitmqadmin` and was able to list all the exchanges and queues. How can I use `rabbitmqadmin` or `rabbitmqctl` to delete all the queues.

Answer (score 326, accepted):

First, list your queues:

`rabbitmqadmin list queues name`

Then from the list, you'll need to manually delete them one by one:

`rabbitmqadmin delete queue name='queuename'`

Because of the output format, doesn't appear you can grep the response from `list queues`. Alternatively, if you're just looking for a way to clear *everything* (read: **reset all settings**, returning the installation to a default state), use:

```
rabbitmqctl stop_app
rabbitmqctl reset    # Be sure you really want to do this!
rabbitmqctl start_app
```

Comment: to see all pending tasks in rabbitmq: `rabbitmqctl list_queues name messages messages_ready \ messages_unacknowledged`

Comment: Be aware that "rabbitmqctl reset" will reset *everything* back to the "factory settings". Any RabbitMQ users, virtual hosts, etc, that you have created will be blown away.

Comment: Apologies @smartnut007, I've clarified the second portion of the answer with a disclaimer.

Comment: just grabbing the empty queues. `rabbitmqctl list_queues | grep 0 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -I qn rabbitmqadmin delete queue name=qn`

Comment: @austin 's receipt works perfectly. Just make sure you have root privilege before you run that.

Comment: @au_stan That will delete all queues with a 0 in the name or the count. Might want to do `grep $'\t0'` or something.

Comment: Is the rabbitmqctl "reset" flavor supposed to be compatible with rabbitmq installed via Homebrew? Didn't seem to work work for me. I ended up using one of the one liner answers.

Comment: @lukiffer i know it's a bit dumb question, but where one should run these commands ??

Comment: @ZeeshanAjmal you can run them from whatever shell you want, so long as they're in your `PATH`.

Comment: seeing answers below this answer seems like a horrible idea. Why would I want to return my all settings to default just because I want to remove some queues.

Comment: Thanks! Only rabbitmqctl reset helped me with queues in a 'stopped' status. Before resetting, you can export the Definitions file, and after resetting, import the Definitions file, and all queues will be in a running status.

Answer (score 151):

**Actually super easy with [management plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#getting-started) and policies:**

- Goto **Management Console** (localhost:15672)
- Goto **Admin** tab
- Goto **Policies** tab(on the right side)
- Add **Policy**
- Fill Fields

  - **Virtual Host:** Select
  - **Name:** Expire All Policies(Delete Later)
  - **Pattern:** .*
  - **Apply to:** Queues
  - **Definition:** **expires** with value **1** (change type from String to Number)
- Save
- Checkout **Queues** tab again
- All Queues must be deleted
- **And don't forget to remove policy!!!!!!**.

Comment: select "Number" at Definition. Does not work with default ("String")

Comment: Great answer, actually made up my day. If you select "Exchanges and Queues" from the list, you could easily delete both Queues and Exchanges. I wish this could be the accepted answer.

Comment: Very clean solution, without the need to play around the instance SSH.

Comment: Pity nobody explains how to install management plugin and policies

Comment: @MesutA. Thanks a lot. I think it's good to have this  link in this article. It might be even better to add it to the answer, as comments might be purged. But I have now at least this info

Comment: @Mesut A. @Mathias Is there any particular reason this does not work for me in 3.8.3? I'm using `.*guid.*` pattern to delete only exchanges/queues that have `guid` string in them, and the policy have no effect.

Comment: @Jaded Number vs String was for the definition field, not for pattern. An older version of this answer did not contain the information to change the type from string to number.

Comment: @Mathias Number vs String for definition is not the case for underlying RabbitMQ version because they've added validator to value field that does not give you ability to add expires = "1", only expires = 1 (Number). To expand on the problem, what I've noticed after adding this policy, it appeared in the "features" column for target exchange ( "D", "ha-all", "NameOfMyPolicy") once (?).

Comment: how can i delete all the exchanges at once ?

Answer (score 67):

With `rabbitmqadmin` you can remove them with this one-liner:

```
rabbitmqadmin -f tsv -q list queues name | while read queue; do rabbitmqadmin -q delete queue name=${queue}; done
```

Comment: In my case queues are prefixed with keyword by which I can simply use `egrep`, so my command will look like this: `rabbitmqadmin -f tsv -q list queues name | egrep "%search word%" | while read queue; do rabbitmqadmin -q delete queue name=${queue}; done`

Comment: You may have to use -H to specify host and -u and -p parameters to specify the credentials to connect to server

Answer (score 32):

In Rabbit version 3.7.10 you can run below command with root permission:

```
rabbitmqctl list_queues | awk '{ print $1 }' | xargs -L1 rabbitmqctl delete_queue
```

Comment: Hmm, I have ran it on Unix based OS and it works successfully, just make sure the result that passed to xargs command is ok.

Comment: for alpine, if you are experiencing `unrecognized option: L`, install `findutils` package - it will get you a GNU version of xargs

Answer (score 22):

Try this:

```
 rabbitmqadmin list queues name | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I qn rabbitmqadmin delete queue name=qn
```

Comment: This worked for me, but also showed `*** Not found: /api/queues/%2F/name` because the output is a ASCII table with a "name" column. I tweaked the command to be ```rabbitmqadmin list queues name | awk '!/--|name/ {print $2}' | xargs -I qn rabbitmqadmin delete queue name=qn``` to fix it.

Comment: ```rabbitmqadmin list queues name | awk {'print$2'} | egrep [^name] | xargs -I qname rabbitmqadmin delete queue name=qname```

Answer (score 15):

If you don't have rabbitmqadmin installed, try to purge queues with rabbitmqctl:

`rabbitmqctl list_queues | awk '{ print $1 }' | xargs -L1 rabbitmqctl purge_queue`

Comment: There is no `delete_queue` nor `purge_queue` commands in `rabbitmqctl`. I would like to purge a lot of queues that seem to be automatically generated and I would not like to install extra software like `rabbitmqadmin`...

Comment: `rabbitmqctl purge_queue` worked here manually. I only needed to add -p <virtual-host>

Comment: Contrary to what @Rolice stated above, both `delete_queue` and `purge_queue` are available in `rabbitmqctl` and I've just run them successfully. Perhaps you're on an old version.

Comment: Good to hear that, these could have been added recently.

Answer (score 13):

If you're trying to delete queues because they're unused and you don't want to reset, one option is to set the queue TTL very low via a policy, wait for the queues to be auto-deleted once the TTL is passed and then remove the policy (https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html).

```
rabbitmqctl.bat set_policy delq ".*" '{"expires": 1}' --apply-to queues
```

To remove the policy

```
rabbitmqctl clear_policy delq
```

Note that this only works for *unused* queues

Original info here: http://rabbitmq.1065348.n5.nabble.com/Deleting-all-queues-in-rabbitmq-td30933.html

Comment: this is the fastest way

Comment: Definitely the best way

Answer (score 6):

I made a deleteRabbitMqQs.sh, which accepts arguments to search the list of queues for, selecting only ones matching the pattern you want. If you offer no arguments, it will delete them all! It shows you the list of queues its about to delete, letting you quit before doing anything destructive.

```
for word in "$@"
do
        args=true
        newQueues=$(rabbitmqctl list_queues name | grep "$word")
        queues="$queues
$newQueues"
done
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        queues=$(rabbitmqctl list_queues name | grep -v "\.\.\.")
fi

queues=$(echo "$queues" | sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d')

if [ "x$queues" == "x" ]; then
        echo "No queues to delete, giving up."
        exit 0
fi

read -p "Deleting the following queues:
${queues}
[CTRL+C quit | ENTER proceed]
"

while read -r line; do
        rabbitmqadmin delete queue name="$line"
done <<< "$queues"
```

If you want different matching against the arguments you pass in, you can alter the grep in line four. When deleting all queues, it won't delete ones with three consecutive spaces in them, because I figured that eventuality would be rarer than people who have rabbitmqctl printing its output out in different languages.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 6):

Here is a way to do it with PowerShell. the URL may need to be updated

```
$cred = Get-Credential
 iwr -ContentType 'application/json' -Method Get -Credential $cred   'http://localhost:15672/api/queues' | % { 
    ConvertFrom-Json  $_.Content } | % { $_ } | ? { $_.messages -gt 0} | % {
    iwr  -method DELETE -Credential $cred  -uri  $("http://localhost:15672/api/queues/{0}/{1}" -f  [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($_.vhost),  $_.name)
 }
```

Comment: Note, this only deletes non-empty queues. Remove the -gt clause to delete all queues

Answer (score 4):

You can use rabbitmqctl eval as below:

```
rabbitmqctl eval 'IfUnused = false, IfEmpty = true, MatchRegex = 
<<"^prefix-">>, [rabbit_amqqueue:delete(Q, IfUnused, IfEmpty) || Q <- 
rabbit_amqqueue:list(), re:run(element(4, element(2, Q)), MatchRegex) 
=/= nomatch ].'
```

The above will delete all empty queues in all vhosts that have a name 
beginning with "prefix-". 
You can edit the variables IfUnused, IfEmpty, 
and MatchRegex as per your requirement.

Comment: Perfect for when `rabbitmqadmin` is not accessible.

Comment: I found this much faster than list_queues

Comment: Has anyone tried this solution with RabbitMQ v3.8.2 or higher? I seem to be running into some undefined Erlang error. Maybe the solution needs to be updated to reflect newer versions?

Comment: I tried similar command as above but get a syntax error before ^
Below is my command.

kubectl exec -n kayaks svc/rabbitmq-ha -- rabbitmqctl --vhost=AM-Dev eval 'IfUnused = false, IfEmpty = true,
MatchRegex = <<"^WOMSProvisioningSubscrptionQueue_platform-">>, [rabbit_amqqueue:delete(Q, IfUnused, IfEmpty) || Q <- 
rabbit_amqqueue:list(), re:run(element(4, element(2, Q)), MatchRegex) 
=/= nomatch ].'

Answer (score 3):

Removing all queues using rabbitmqctl one liner

```
rabbitmqctl list_queues | awk '{ print $1 }' | sed 's/Listing//' | xargs -L1 rabbitmqctl purge_queue
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried rabbitmqctl and reset commands but they are very slow.

This is the fastest way I found (replace your username and password):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Stop on error
set -eo pipefail

USER='guest'
PASSWORD='guest'

curl -sSL -u $USER:$PASSWORD http://localhost:15672/api/queues/%2f/ | jq '.[].name' | sed 's/"//g' | xargs -L 1 -I@ curl -XDELETE -sSL -u $USER:$PASSWORD http://localhost:15672/api/queues/%2f/@
# To also delete exchanges uncomment next line
# curl -sSL -u $USER:$PASSWORD http://localhost:15672/api/exchanges/%2f/ | jq '.[].name' | sed 's/"//g' | xargs -L 1 -I@ curl -XDELETE -sSL -u $USER:$PASSWORD http://localhost:15672/api/exchanges/%2f/@
```

Note: This only works with the default vhost /

Comment: Thanks! Way better way than most other suggestions

Answer (score 2):

You need not reset rabbitmq server to delete *non-durable* queues. Simply stop the server and start again and it will remove all the *non-durable* queues available.

Comment: including durable queues? I don't think so. I'll qualify your answer.

Comment: No, durable queues cannot be deleted by stopping the server. They can be deleted from RabbitMQ Management web interface under queues.

Comment: Actually yes, this helped me and all about 4500 automatically generated queues are gone. It seems that these were non-durable ones. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In case you only want to purge the queues which are not empty (a lot faster):

```
rabbitmqctl list_queues | awk '$2!=0 { print $1 }' | sed 's/Listing//' | xargs -L1 rabbitmqctl purge_queue
```

For me, it takes 2-3 seconds to purge a queue (both empty and non-empty ones), so iterating through 50 queues is such a pain while I just need to purge 10 of them (40/50 are empty).

Answer (score 2):

I tried the above pieces of code but I did not do any streaming.

`sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues | awk '{print $1}' > queues.txt; for line in $(cat queues.txt); do sudo rabbitmqctl delete_queue "$line"; done`.

I generate a file that contains all the queue names and loops through it line by line to the delete them. For the loops, `while read ...` did not do it for me. It was always stopping at the first queue name.

Answer (score 2):

For whose have a problem with installing rabbitmqadmin, You should firstly install python.

UNIX-like operating system users need to copy rabbitmqadmin to a directory in PATH, e.g. /usr/local/bin.

Windows users will need to ensure Python is on their PATH, and invoke rabbitmqadmin as python.exe rabbitmqadmin.

Then

1. Browse to `http://{hostname}:15672/cli/rabbitmqadmin` to download.
2. Go to the containing folder then run cmd with administrator privilege

**To list Queues** 
`python rabbitmqadmin list queues`.

**To delete Queue** 
`python rabbitmqadmin delete queue name=Name_of_queue`

**To Delete all Queues**

1- Declare Policy

```
python rabbitmqadmin declare policy name='expire_all_policies' pattern=.* definition={\"expires\":1} apply-to=queues
```

2- Remove the policy

```
python rabbitmqadmin  delete policy name='expire_all_policies'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a faster version (using `parallel` install sudo apt-get install parallel) expanding on the excellent answer by @admenva

`parallel  -j 50 rabbitmqadmin -H YOUR_HOST_OR_LOCALHOST -q delete queue name={} ::: $(rabbitmqadmin -H  YOUR_HOST_OR_LOCALHOST -f tsv -q list queues name)`

Answer (score 1):

This commands deletes all your queues

```
python rabbitmqadmin.py \
  -H YOURHOST -u guest -p guest -f bash list queues | \
xargs -n1 | \
xargs -I{} \
  python rabbitmqadmin.py -H YOURHOST -u guest -p guest delete queue name={}
```

This script is super simple because it uses `-f bash`, which outputs the queues as a list.

Then we use `xargs -n1` to split that up into multiple variables

Then we use `xargs -I{}` that will run the command following, and replace `{}` in the command.

Comment: I've tried like 10 different answers, and this is the ONLY thing that has actually worked to delete queues without killing all my other settings. Thanks! I can't believe rabbitmqctl doesn't just have a "drop all queues" command.

Comment: BTW, to get rabbitmqadmin, you need to go to `http://yourhost:15672/cli/` and download it.

Answer (score 1):

To list queues,

```
./rabbitmqadmin -f tsv -q list queues
```

To delete a queue,

```
./rabbitmqadmin delete queue name=name_of_queue
```

Answer (score 1):

Following command worked for me:

`sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -I qn sudo rabbitmqctl delete_queue qn`

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to remove all queues and exchanges without scripts and full reset. You can just delete and re-create a virtual host from admin interface. This will work even for vhost `/`.

The only thing you'll need to restore is permissions for the newly created vhost.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, important qualifier for this answer:
The question does ask to use either **rabbitmqctl** OR **rabbitmqadmin** to solve this, my answer needed to use both. Also, note that this was tested on MacOS 10.12.6 and the versions of the **rabbitmqctl** and **rabbitmqadmin** that are installed when installing rabbitmq with Homebrew and which is identified with `brew list --versions` as **rabbitmq 3.7.0**

`rabbitmqctl list_queues -p <VIRTUAL_HOSTNAME> name | sed 1,2d | xargs -I qname rabbitmqadmin --vhost <VIRTUAL_HOSTNAME> delete queue name=qname`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to delete the vhost associated with the queues. This will delete *everything* associated with the vhost, so be warned, but it is easy and fast.

Answer (score 0):

This is a method I use. It is easy, clear and effective.
This is [the document](https://pulse.mozilla.org/api/index.html):

```sh
Vhost=the_vhost_name
User=user_name
Password=the_passworld

for i in `rabbitmqctl list_queues -p $Vhost |  awk '{ print $1 }'`
do
    echo "queu_name: $i"
    curl  -u $User:$Passworld -H "content-type:application/json"  -XDELETE http://localhost:15672/api/queues/$Vhost/$i
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
rabbitmqctl list_queues -q name > q.txt
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a queues < q.txt
count=${#queues[@]}
i=1; while (($i < $count)); do echo ${queues[$i]};rabbitmqctl delete_queue ${queues[$i]};i=$((i+1)); done
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/52002145/3278855

To automate that, it's possible to use this curl:

```bash
curl -X PUT --data '{"pattern":".*","apply-to":"all","definition":{"expires":1},"priority":0}' -u guest:guest 'http://localhost:15672/api/policies/%2f/clear' && \
curl -X DELETE -u guest:guest 'http://localhost:15672/api/policies/%2f/clear'
```

Please note that `%2f` is default vhost name (`/`) and `guest:guest` is login:password

Answer (score -1):

```
rabbitmqadmin list queues|awk 'NR>3{print $4}'|head -n-1|xargs -I qname rabbitmqadmin delete queue name=qname
```

Comment: I receive this when running it:
head: illegal line count -- -1

Comment: The "head -n-1" should be either "head -1" or "head -n 1"