# unable to connect to node rabbit@localhost: nodedown

Tags: linux, terminal, rabbitmq, celery

When I am running my celerybeat service I am getting a ton of received tasks back:

```
[2015-07-31 11:15:46,593: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: tasks2.energy[89544]
[2015-07-31 11:15:46,594: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: tasks2.energy[97083]
[2015-07-31 11:15:46,594: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: tasks2.energy[3d476]
```

Other posts have said to purge any queues. However, I keep running into errors such as the one in the title. Here is the referenced post:
[Delete all the queues from RabbitMQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459676/how-to-delete-all-the-queues-from-rabbitmq)

I run `rabbitmqctl stop_app`, and I get

```
DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: [rabbit@localhost]

rabbit@localhost:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on localhost
  * epmd reports: node 'rabbit' not running at all
                  other nodes on localhost: ['rabbitmq-cli-16558']
  * suggestion: start the node

current node details:
- node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-16558@Pete_Zahut's-MacBook-Pro'
- home dir: /var/root
- cookie hash: Pete Zahut
```

When I run `rabbitmqadmin list queues name` I get

```
Could not connect: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

Celery --purge option fixes this!

Comment: What's the meaning of your answer?